# How to fetch the first occurences in a list in amzi prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

This is so far the .pro file I could think of. I want to print / get / output the first occurrence (=first Head) of "thelist".

```
thelist([a,b,c,d,e]).

head(H,[H|T]).
```

Why it always return NO at all time?
Thanks

Comment: I forgot the question... Question : Why it always return NO at all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
...
thelist([H|_]), write(H), nl,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can also use this way :

```
thelist(X),first(F,X).
```

But below code must be added to the knowledge base (.pro file)

```
first(F,[F|_]).
```

replacing the

```
head(H,[H|T]).
```